# Where's the documentation for integration?

Tags: paypal

Sounds an odd question since there's a whole PayPal developer section...

About a decade ago I wrote the code to integrate our e-com solution with PayPal.

Customer on merchant site > basket > login or register > checkout > pay using PayPal button > user goes to PayPal site and pays > e-com solution receives background post ("IPN?") to notify it of payment received > customer sent back to merchant site which then shows result.

Was a long time ago. E-com codebase was completely reworked. We didn't include PayPal at that time.

Looking for the documentation for same to do same. PayPal is never used by any of our merchants as the primary payment provider so this is an additional option to be provided at the checkout. So, not interested in the customer leaving the merchant's site at the basket, nor any of the more advanced features, nor uploading the cart contents.

I've spent ages trying to hunt this down. It looks like it's called "PayPal Payments Standard". The documentation argues with itself about whether this is for single items or multiple (e.g. a basket). Not interested in passing across the items, just the amount to pay.

From what I can see, the methodology is the same as it ever was except that I need to create a "button" labelled "Pay Now" - amount is the entire cart, the item is "cart contents" by calling the API to get me back the button code and thus the link that takes the user to PayPal. Every button created this way will say "Pay Now" and a new button is needed for every single transaction. There is however something nagging at me that this is not quite right.

I thought I'd found the documentation - the PDF integration guide. That just comes up with a link saying it's moved. Click that and I get a link saying it's moved. Click that and I'm back at the PayPal site again - no PDF. Round and round we go.

I must just be getting old or going blind.

Can anyone point me at the right solution and where the documentation is. Am an experienced coder so ideally I just want a PDF and sample code.

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: this is a lot of words but im still not sure what you are asking. recommend editing this to be just a couple sentences explaining what you are looking for

Comment: Is [this](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/gs_PayPalPaymentsStandard/) what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks Doug - no I don't think it is. That makes mention of creating a PayPal Add to Cart button. E-com solution has a cart. All I want to use PayPal for is to collect payment for the total order. That page implies that PayPal Payments Standard is not the solution I need, yet other PayPal pages say that it is.

Comment: @Robert: Customer on merchant site > basket > login or register > checkout > pay using PayPal button > user goes to PayPal site and pays > e-com solution receives background post ("IPN?") to notify it of payment received > customer sent back to merchant site which then shows result. < is what I want to achieve. What's this solution called and where's a worked example?

Comment: Aha - I think I might have been on the right lines. It is PayPal Payments Standard and it's "Using the Button Manager API With Hosted Solution Checkout" found from Doug's link.

Comment: OK then - here's that link: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/button-manager/integration-guide/NVP/ButtonMgrAPI/#idffdd7aa9-6d3a-45a8-8c9f-76edcd6c99e4

Comment: Where's the documentation? Any sample code? That's just a code snippet. Lots of pages with lots of code snippets. There's also a download page of SDKs with meaningless names. Does PayPal "do" documentation? I've integrated with just about every PSP going over the years, but this is like stumbling across some sort of private members club.

Comment: OK - I give up. Have never seen anything like this, it's a joke. Am guessing the new features have run well ahead of putting up any documentation. Have asked PayPal directly for documentation and code samples for the kind of really simple integration that would take less time to code with SagePay than it takes to hunt down the docs on PayPal. Thanks.